# Java Spring, @RequestBody - how to receive valid JSON with two connected entities

Tags: java, json, spring

I've got simple

### DB SCHEMA

```
Contact
-------
int: id
varchar: name

Note
-------
int: id
int: id_contact
varchar: title
```

As you can see, tables are connected. My goal is to add note by AJAX request with id_contact provided.

### FORM should look like that

```
<form action="add-note" id="add-note">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_contact" value="20" /> <!-- just a dummy value which corresponds with contact record in DB -->

    note: 
    <input type="text" name="title" class="title">

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

### Method to process AJAX request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-note", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Note> addNote(@RequestBody Note note) {

    // do something with note...

    return new ResponseEntity<Note>(note, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If I don't try to provide id_contact, method addNote works fine, but I'm not able to make spring to convert JSON to Note with Contact in it.

Does anyone know how to achieve it? Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:
After all, I ended up with passing id_contact as GET param and handling it like that:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNote", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Note> addNote(@RequestBody Note note, @RequestParam(value = "id_contact") long id_contact) {

            note.setContact(contact_service.findOne(id_contact));
            note_service.insert(note);

            return new ResponseEntity<Note>(note, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

Feel free to answer to my question above - I consider this snippet as a little workaround. (But maybe it's the right way how you would do it by urself?)

---

EDIT2:

### Note.java

```
// imports ommited    
@Entity
    public class Note {

        @Id
        @JsonProperty("url")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id_contact")
        private Contact contact;

        private String title;
// setters/getters ommited
```

Error I get when trying to send JSON is "400 bad request".

Comment: Please post your code for `Note`, and perhaps a stacktrace as well, or some other indication of what you think went wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON you're sending in the request body?

Comment: 1) What works: {title: 'test'}, 2) what doesn't work: {contact: '20', title: 'test'} or {contact.id: '20', title: 'test'}, or {id_contact: '20', title: 'test'}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to work but try to use dot operator.

```
<input type="hidden" name="contact.id" value="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact.name" value="20" />
```

RequestBody will try to map the notes Entity, and using nested objects sometimes works.

If not considering creating a json request instead of use the multpart form format.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your examples from your comments is valid JSON. I believe `{"title": "test", "contact" : {"id" : 20}}` would work for you in a sense that it will be parsed by Spring properly into a `Note`. However your form won't produce any JSON, and I can't see any AJAX calls anywhere in your post.

Comment: Ur example makes sense. But it implies I should User object define in javascript before sending form by ajax. - this.model.set("user", {"id": 20}); // using backbone here, I thought there will be more straight way to achieve it in spring.

Comment: If you want Spring to parse your JSON RequestBody into an Object, it has to be a JSON represenation of that Object. If you don't want to do that, you have to pass Ids and build the Object manually like you do in your EDIT. I can't see any other way.